# Xcode 12.5 beta 3, Swift 5.3 fails to check Any for nil value

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the following test that succeeds in **all Xcode versions** released for last few years **except for Xcode 12.5 beta 3**:

```
var nilString: String? = nil
var dict: [String: Any] = ["hello": nilString as Any]
var element = dict["hello"] as Any
print(element)
print(type(of: element))

switch element {
    case Optional<Any>.none:
        print("element is nil")
    default:
        assertionFailure("element is not nil. wtf?")
}
```

In Xcode 12.4 I get this printed

```
Optional(nil)
Optional<Any>
element is nil
```

Wheras in Xcode 12.5 beta 3 I get this printed

```
Optional(nil)
Optional<Any>
Fatal error: element is not nil. wtf?
```

Can somebody shed some light on this issue? How can I check Any for nil now? Would it be fixed in release candidate?

**UPDATED**
Want to be confused even more?

```
var nilString: String? = nil
var element: Any = nilString as Any
print(element)
print(type(of: element.self))

switch element {
    case Optional<Any>.none:
        print("element is nil")
    default:
        assertionFailure("element is not nil")
}
```

outputs:

```
nil
Optional<String>
element is nil
```

I suppose something wrong happens with my nilString when being put in dictionary.

Comment: An optional `Dictionary` value undermines the rule that the key is being removed when the value is set to `nil`. In Objective-C `NSDictionary` `nil` values are not allowed anyway.

Comment: I don't know what changed, but that print-wording is inaccurate. `nil as String?` / `Optional<String>.none` work where the `Any` does not. I.e. you can find `nil`, but you have to know its type.

Comment: @Jessy nevertheless, `print(type(of: element))` gives me `Optional<Any>`

Comment: @Jessy I've updated my question

Comment: It is an `Optional<Any>`, but it's not `Optional<Any>.none`. It has a value. You're not taking the double-optional into account.

Comment: @Jessy if this is a double optional, I should be able to unwrap one from another...

Comment: You should, but I don't know how to do it without a Mirror, given that you've obfuscated optionality twice with the `as Any`. Is reflection acceptable?

Comment: @Jessy I think I made it. let me doublecheck...

Comment: @Jessy pls check my answer, I still may miss something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Jessy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/652038/jessy) for pointing out on the idea that `Optional<Any>` may actually have `some` value inside and that could be `nil`. I've come up with a function that checks Any for nil and it works in both old and newest Xcode (something has definitely been changed in 12.5 beta 3 that had broken the old test, i.e. putting nil casted to Any into a dictionary value leads the value to be wrapped into `Optional<Any>.some` instead of treating it as `Optional<Any>.none`):

```
func isOptional(_ instance: Any) -> Bool {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: instance)
    let style = mirror.displayStyle
    return style == .optional
}

func checkIfAnyIsNil(_ v: Any) -> Bool {
    if (isOptional(v)) {
        switch v {
        case Optional<Any>.none:
            return true
        case Optional<Any>.some(let v):
            return checkIfAnyIsNil(v)
        default:
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

assertions:

```
var nilString: String? = nil
var dict: [String: Any] = ["nilString": nilString as Any]

assert(checkIfAnyIsNil(dict["nilString"] as Any))
assert(checkIfAnyIsNil(nilString as Any))
assert(checkIfAnyIsNil("some string" as Any) == false)
```